# Erlang - String into Set

Tags: erlang

I am currently trying to understand the behavior of Erlang Sets, when I compute Sets on String Anagrams. In my understanding, two Anagrams should produce two identical Sets of strings.

```
Set1 = sets:from_list("orchestra"). 
Set2 = sets:from_list("carthorse"). 
Set1 =:= Set2. %% true
```

However, using `sets:intersection` we receive a different set, which is not equal to the first two sets.

```
Intersection = sets:intersection(Set1, Set2). 
Intersection =:= Set1. %% false
Intersection =:= Set2. %% false
```

Is there a particular reason for this behavior, based on how Set-Intersections are computed in Erlang?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the `sets` module does not guarantee that two sets can be compared with `=:=` even if they contain the same elements. The internal data structure can differ. You could use operations like `is_subset/2` or `subtract/2` (relatively inefficient), or you could use `to_list/1` and then `lists:sort/1` to get two lists that could be compared directly. But if you're starting from strings (lists of characters) anyway, you would be better off using `ordsets` right away. These are ordered lists which you can manipulate as sets, and can be directly compared. For small-ish sets they are usually more efficient that `sets` anyway.

```
> Set1 = ordsets:from_list("orchestra").
"acehorst"
> Set2 = ordsets:from_list("carthorse").
"acehorst"
> Set1 =:= Set2.
true
> Intersection = ordsets:intersection(Set1, Set2).
"acehorst"
> Intersection =:= Set1.
true
> Intersection =:= Set2.
true
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation regarding ordsets, which is exactly what I was looking for! Coming from Clojure, I expected a behavior comparable to (= (set "carthorse") (clojure.set/intersection (set "orchestra") (set "carthorse")) ) => true

Answer (score 1):

The `=:=` operator compares the representations of `Set1` and `Intersection`, but there's no guarantee what the representations are or that the same set only has one representation.

The documentation of [sets](https://erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html) only talks about `=:=` when it describes how it compares elements of sets, not the sets themselves.

For set equality, you can define

```
set_eq(S1, S2) ->
    sets:is_subset(S1, S2) andalso sets:is_subset(S2, S1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the code and look at what happens along the way.

We are defining 2 sets

```
Set1 = sets:from_list("orchestra"). 
{set,8,16,16,8,80,48,
     {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
     {{[],"sc",[],[],[],"o","r","e","h",[],[],"a","t",[],[],[]}}}
```

and

```
Set2 = sets:from_list("carthorse"). 
{set,8,16,16,8,80,48,
     {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
     {{[],"sc",[],[],[],"o","r","e","h",[],[],"a","t",[],[],[]}}}
```

where the second lines represent the values created with a representation. So based on the above definition, we infer that the representation chosen for storing sets is of a tuple.

We can refer to the [Term Comparison](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#term-comparisons) section of Erlang Reference manual which states that

*`...Lists are compared element by element. Tuples are ordered by size, two tuples with the same size are compared element by element...`*

Having that as an invariant, now lets look at the set which comes about after an `intersection`

```
Intersection = sets:intersection(Set1, Set2).
{set,8,16,16,8,80,48,
     {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
     {{[],"cs",[],[],[],"o","r","e","h",[],[],"a","t",[],[],[]}}}
```

Again, this being a set gets the same underlying representation of the tuple, but if we look at the last element, there is a string (essentially a list of characters in Erlang) `"cs"`, which is different in value in the same place when we defined `Set1` and `Set2`. And hence the inequality as per the `Term Comparison`.

Now, let's attempt to change the sub-value `"cs"` inside `Intersection` to `"sc"` and then as per the `Term Comparison` rules, two sets must satisfy equality.

```
Improvised_Intersection = setelement(9, Intersection, {setelement(2, element(1, element(9, Intersection)), "sc")}).
{set,8,16,16,8,80,48,
     {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
     {{[],"sc",[],[],[],"o","r","e","h",[],[],"a","t",[],[],[]}}}
```

And now let's compare `Improvised_Intersection` with `Set1` and `Set2`, which gives

```
Improvised_Intersection =:= Set1.                                                                                  
true

Improvised_Intersection =:= Set2.                                                                                  
true

Intersection =:= Improvised_Intersection.
false
```

It's just an attempt to provide some insight into what already @Richard and others have pointed out.

Comment: Just our of curiosity, what happends under the hood, when the list of (individual) characters is mapped to the values "cs" or "sc", respectively. Is this the result of a hash function?

Comment: And you could be quite correct. Maps are at play under the hood, as per [sets](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/sets.erl#L256)